# do webrtc's api have any limitations?

Tags: webrtc

What are the limitations of WebRTC's APIs, if any?

What is the maximum number of peers that can be connected at a time? I mean, since webRTC is peer-to-peer, hardware and bandwidth resources are divided among peers, a single server is not responsible for handling media streams, then how many maximum users can we connect by using webRTC?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. I suggest you do some reading and then post on the Discuss-WebRTC google group.

Comment: The limitation you mention, bandwith, is not in the API, but inherent in peer-to-peer communication in general. Usually, client upload speed is the gating item, but it all depends on what you got, and how it is used, e.g. mesh call, star topology, use of MCU server. It also depends on resolution, and what you are sending: video, audio, or even just data (it's still WebRTC even if you use just data channels).

Comment: @jib So, supposing an ideal scenario, where each peer has unlimited bandwidth and unlimited hardware resources. WebRTC, itself won't limit any connections and unlimited peers can connect to each other at a given time?

Comment: @panther1 I'm aware of no inherent limitations in the spec. Implementations may vary, but AFAIK all limitations are external. You'd probably run out of port numbers first.